# Android - Simple XML Framework. @Convert interferes with @Attribute - How to solve this?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, converters, simple-framework

I was working on capturing the order of elements contained in tag. Here is all the code:

**League.java:**

```
@Root
@Convert(value = LeagueConverter.class)
public class League 
{
    @Attribute
    private String name;

    @Element(name="headlines", required = false)
    private Headlines headlines;

    @Element(name="scores", required = false)
    private Scores scores;

    @Element(name="standings", required = false)
    private Standing standings;

    @Element(name="statistics", required = false)
    private LeagueStatistics statistics;

    public List<String> order = new ArrayList<String>();

        // get methods for all variables
}
```

**LeagueConverter.java:**

```
public class LeagueConverter implements Converter<League>
{
       @Override
       public League read(InputNode node) throws Exception
       {
               League league = new League();
               InputNode next = node.getNext();
               while( next != null )
               {
                String tag = next.getName();
                if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("headlines"))
                {
                  league.order.add("headlines");
                }
                else if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("scores"))
                    {
                          league.order.add("scores");
                    }
                else if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("statistics"))
                {
                  league.order.add("statistics");
                }
                else if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("standings"))
                {
                  league.order.add("standings");
                }
                    next = node.getNext();
                }
                return league;
       }
   @Override
   public void write(OutputNode arg0, League arg1) throws Exception 
   {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
   }
}
```

**Exampe of XML:**

```
 <android>
    <leagues>
       <league name ="A">
          <Headlines></Headlines>
          <Scores></Scores>
          ...
       </league>
       <league name ="B">...</league>
    </leagues>
 </android>
```

**How I'm calling it and expecting it to behave:** (Snippet)

```
 Android android = null;
 Serializer serial = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());

 android = serial.read(Android.class, source);
 Log.i("Number of leagues found ",tsnAndroid.getLeagueCount() + ""); // prints fine
 League nhl = tsnAndroid.getLeagues().get(0); // works fine

 // DOES NOT WORK throws NullPointerEx
 League nhl2 = tsnAndroid.getLeagueByName("A");
 // DOES NOT WORK throws NullPointerEx

 for(String s : nhl.getOrder())
 {
    Log.i("ORDER>>>>>", s);
 }
```

**The problem:**

`android.getLeagueByName()` (Works with `@Attribute` name) suddenly stops working when I have the converter set, so its like the following from `League.java`, never gets set.

```
@Attribute
private String name; // not being set
```

However, when I comment out the converter declaration in `League.java` - Every league has an attribute called name and `android.getLeagueByName()` starts working fine...

**Does @Convert for League somehow interfere with @Attribute in League?**

Comment: What is the `getLeagueByName()` doing? Did you check if your league-list contains any not-`null` values? Possible the list has the correct count of elements, but all of them are `null`.

Comment: I just checked what league was returning. It seems when I comment out the @convert - leagues itself are null because the android element doesn't parse. However I'm not sure why.

Comment: You can debug each deserialization (each object), maybe only one fails and causes a `null`.

Answer (score 5):

Even though this question is outrageously old (as is the SimpleXML library), I will give my two cents.

**@Convert** annotation works only with **@Element**, but it does not have any effect on **@Attribute**. I'm not sure if that's a bug or a feature, but there is another way of handling custom serialized objects  - called **Transform** with **Matcher**, and it works both with **Attributes** and with **Elements**. Instead of using the **Converter**s, you define a **Transform** class that handles serialization and deserialization:

```
import java.util.UUID;
import org.simpleframework.xml.transform.Transform;

public class UUIDTransform implements Transform<UUID> {
    @Override
    public UUID read(String value) throws Exception {
        return value != null ? UUID.fromString(value) : null;
    }
    @Override
    public String write(UUID value) throws Exception {
        return value != null ? value.toString() : null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is more straight-forward than implementing the Convert interface!

Create a similar class for all your objects that require custom de/serialization.

Now instantiate a **RegistryMatcher** object and register there your custom classes with their corresponding **Transform** classes. This is a thread-safe object that internally uses a cache, so it might be a good idea to keep it as a singleton.

```
private static final RegistryMatcher REGISTRY_MATCHER = new RegistryMatcher();
static {
    try {
        REGISTRY_MATCHER.bind(UUID.class, UUIDTransform.class);
        // register all your Transform classes here...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can create a **Persister** class each time before a conversion and pass it the **AnnotationStrategy** together with your **RegistryMatcher** instance. In this factory method below, we will also use an indenting formatter:

```
private static Persister createPersister(int indent) {
    return new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy(), REGISTRY_MATCHER, new Format(indent));
}
```

Now you can make your serialization/deserialization methods:

```
public static String objectToXml(Object object, int indent) throws MyObjectConversionException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Persister p = createPersister(indent);
    try {
        p.write(object, out, "UTF-8");
        return out.toString("UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyObjectConversionException("Cannot serialize object " + object + " to XML: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public static <T> T xmlToObject(String xml, final Class<T> clazz) throws MyObjectConversionException {
    Persister p = createPersister(0);
    try {
        return (T) p.read(clazz, xml);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyObjectConversionException(
                "Cannot deserialize XML to object of type " + clazz + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

The only issue with this approach is when you want to have different formatting for the same object - e.g. once you want the **java.util.Date** to have just the date component, while later on you also want to have the time component. Then just extend the **Date** class, calling it **DateWithTime**, and make a different **Transform** for it.

Answer (score 1):

@ElementListUnion will capture the order of elements

Comment: Doesn't this only work if all the elements in the union are element lists?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Convert` annotation works only on `@Element` fields. I am struggling against converting `@Attribute` fields too but with no success for now...

Comment: Not true. Simple xml allows the use of @Convert on the class level too. http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Convert.html